# Script on the page used too much memory. Reload to enable script again

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript to generate a dynamic report. If I open the page in full screen mode, the browser shows:

> "Script on the page used too much memory. Reload to enable script
>   again".

After getting this error, other pages also stop working. It doesn't even work after logging out and logging back in. If I open a new tab, only other pages work.

Can anybody explain what this error means, and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean Java, or JavaScript? These are totally different things...

Comment: According to your description it seems that the JavaScript code is probably making too much memory allocation.
Could you please show us the code you are using?